# Problems with NVIDIA drivers: White screen with full(or almost full)screen apps

Tags: drivers, nvidia

My NVIDIA graphic card is a 7050/610i.
My problem is that after upgrading to the last NVIDIA drivers when I use fullscreen apps (or almost fullscreen) the windows goes white.

My xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 270.29  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-02.nvidia.com)  Wed Feb 23 16:38:34 PST 2011

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    Option         "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    # generated from default
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Driver  "nvidia"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

<--Sorry for bad english, ask for more info-->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

- Click on the Ubuntu-Symbol in the top left corner
- Type hardware and select hardware-drivers
- Activate driver number 173

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10748878

**Background:**

There is a launchpad entry describing this bug and any progress towards solving it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/773582